# Question about quantum gis, and importing csv point data

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm trying to add some point data from a csv file (it's in decimal degree lat lon) and overlay  over road data that I already have added. The problem is that I can't get it to line up.  I'm sure I'm making some kind of mistake with the coordinate system, but I can't figure out what it is.  The data appears to the left and down miles away from my road data. When I import the same data in arcgis, I have to choose GCS_North_American_1983_HARN as my geographic coordinate system to make it line up, but that does not seem to be an option in quantum gis.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean with "that does not seem to be an option"? Can you not find the CRS in the list? Or is it that you do not know where to set the CRS?

Comment: There is a good question on a similar issue and how to solve it [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72430/projection-system-differs)

Answer (score 1):

GCS_North_American_1983_HARN is EPSG:4152, but that should line up with EPSG:4326 WGS 84.

What CRS have you chosen for your road data? That would be most surely in a projected CRS using metres or feet as units.

If you have activated "On-the-fly-reprojection", your data should align, if both layers have correct CRS assigned.

Please look up the extent of the two layers with rightclick, Properties, metadata tab.

If you are in doubt which layer is right, change the **project** CRS to EPSG:3857, and add an Openstreetmap or Google background via the Openlayers plugin.